# What makes the Night King different from other white walkers?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

What makes the Night King different from other White Walkers in *Game of Thrones*?

Is that it is only the Night King who can change humans to White Walkers?

If not, who else who all can do this conversion? Are all the White Walkers able to do this?

What makes the Night King different from the other White Walkers?

What are his special abilities?

I am asking specifically about the conversion to White Walkers, not Wights.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91722/just-how-many-white-walkers-are-there

Comment: This link also doesnt answer about the conversion which is the main part of my question @Paulie_D

Comment: Since this hasn't been revealed in the show there is no other answer...

Comment: Well..thats atleast an answer...the question is not a repetition

Comment: So do you want "We don't know" as an answer? Seems unnecessary.

Comment: Yet another *Game of Thrones* question that is asking for stuff that is yet unrevealed, and will therefore yield "I don' know" answers or, even worse, pure speculation answers. I voted to close.

Comment: @GhotiandChips It feels like that is the only kind of GoT question now.  I think the Unsullied got spoiled by 5 years of book readers able to answer any question they may have...

Answer (score 3):

The night king is the original white walker.  He was created by the children of the forest when they plunged a dragonglass dagger into the heart of a person (probably a stark but we don't know for sure).
So far we have only seen the night king convert humans into white walkers and I think the night king is the only one who has the power to create white walkers.  A white walker brought Craster's last son all the way north to meet the night king where the night king turned him into a white walker.  If regular white walkers could turn people then there would be no reason to keep the baby human for the whole journey.

Answer (score 1):

He was the first white walker made by the children of the forest to protect against humans. Wights  are created by any white walker.

Source: http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Night_King

Comment: Actually the link helped me alot...and avoided the confusion between night king and the night's king

Comment: And yet down voted???

Comment: Pls have my upvote

Comment: Just kidding. It's Game of Thrones. Not the cure for cancer. Apologies if I sounded snarky.

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted your answer...i upvoted only

Comment: You know how important punctuation is. Without commas, we'd say, "It's time to eat grandma" instead of "it's time to eat, Grandma" and apostrophes are just inverted commas.